# Настройка nginx + java

Tags: nginx, html, java

Организовываю связку: клиент html<---->|сервер nginx <-> сервер java|

Как настроить конфиг nginx'a, чтобы он мог работать в связке с java сервером? В интернете по этому поводу ничего не нашел(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать nginx в качестве proxy. Например, что-то вроде такого

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myserver.ru;

    access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8080/;  # my java server port 8080
        proxy_redirect     off;

        # дальше всякая шелуха по поводу размеров всяких буфферов, таймаутов proxy и т.п.
    }
}
```

**UPD** В догонку можете посмотреть более детальное описание на сайте nginx: [Java servers like Jetty, GlassFish and Tomcat](http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers)

Answer (score 0):

Можно поступить аналогично секции для PHP и перенаправлять запросы для файлов .jsf на ваш java сервер. Соответственно, лучше соединять их через unix сокеты, если возможно.
Естественно, этот вариант был бы лучше. Т.к. в случае простого проксирования nginx хорош, но не раскрывает своих возможностей. Как минимум, лучше разделить статику с java на разные каталоги и статику поручить nginx, а java файлы передавать на обработку java серверу.